# Error message "Make sure the GraphQL service is installed and available"

Tags: graphql, sitecore-cli

Installed fresh Sitecore 10 and trying to use Sitecore CLI combined with native Sitecore Content Serialization.
When executing next command

```
dotnet sitecore ser pull
```

I get an error message

```
Make sure the GraphQL service is installed and available.
```

Anyone has an idea on what's missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure you've installed the Sitecore Management Services module.

It's listed as a pre-req here: https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/100/developer-tools/en/install-sitecore-command-line-interface.html

dead link on the documentation website was supposed to lead me here:
https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_CLI/2x/Sitecore_CLI_200.aspx

Comment: Hi there,

I already installed the Sitecore Management Services package but still get "Make sure the GraphQL service is installed and available."

I really do not know what happened. Any help!? Please,

Comment: This doesn't seem like the correct answer to this issue.  I am receiving the same error message after installing the Sitecore CLI, as listed in this link.

Comment: Been through all of these and none of them worked for me. I have installed and re-installed Sitecore CLI, but getting same error message. My http settings are correct as well both identity server and website are "https". Any other help or suggestions?

Answer (score 9):

We also faced a similar issue so we added **https://** in our instance name in `user.json (\.sitecore\user.json)` and then tried again and it worked for us. Make sure you have `https://` in your instance, then try.

```
"host": "https://sc10sc.dev.local",
"authority": "https://sc10identityserver.dev.local"
```

Comment: solved thank you

Comment: That solved my problem. Not sure what causes sitecore CLI saved http:// instead of https:// in user.json file after login. Ton of thanks!

Comment: Been through all of these and none of them worked for me. I have installed and re-installed Sitecore CLI, but getting same error message. My http settings are correct as well both identity server and website are "https". Any other help or suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

This is an extension of the answer by Gaurav.

The Sitecore CLI saves the values in user.json based on the values that you provide in login command.

```
dotnet sitecore login --authority https://id.dockerbase.localhost --cm https://cm.dockerbase.localhost --allow-write true
```

My issue was that I had given http in CM url.

Comment: Yup I did the same thing. Thanks for this answer!

Answer (score 1):

I got that very error message these days when running `dotnet sitecore ser pull` or `dotnet sitecore ser push`.

I was able to fix it by reinstalling in CM the *Sitecore.ManagementServices* package from  https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_CLI/5x/Sitecore_CLI_5125.aspx

You can follow these instructions https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/102/developer-tools/sitecore-management-services.html

*Be sure to install the right package*, compatible with Sitecore CLI version you installed. I had previously installed the wrong package, installing the correct one fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting this error for non-interactive login, then make sure that the source & target env's  `Dotnet tool` version is the same. you can find this info under (/.config/dotnet-tools.json)

Eg:

```
{
  "version": 1,
  "isRoot": true,
  "tools": {
    "sitecore.cli": {
      "version": "4.1.0",
      "commands": [
        "sitecore"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it turned out to be `Sitecore topology mismatch.`

**Explanation** : I was using Sitecore Content Serialization (SCS) 4.0.0 for Sitecore 10.2 `XM` and in the docker compose XM override file, for CM image, Management services argument, I was passing XP image reference `scr.sitecore.com/sxp/modules/sitecore-management-services-xp1-assets:4.0.0-1809`
Once I changed it to  **scr.sitecore.com/sxp/modules/sitecore-management-services-xm1-assets:4.0.0-1809** , I was able to successfully use SCS.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to fix my configuration by connecting XM Cloud and local environments.

```
dotnet sitecore cloud environment connect -id <environment-id> --allow-write true

dotnet sitecore connect --ref xmcloud --cm https://xmcloudcm.localhost --allow-write true -n local
```

Details are described [here](https://doc.sitecore.com/xmc/en/developers/xm-cloud/walkthrough--setting-up-your-full-stack-xm-cloud-local-development-environment.html)